# Python Sequence Comparison

Tags: python, comparison

I'm trying to compare two sequences:

```py
>>> seq_a = "tgaaactcaagccttaccgcagagacagaagaaacagcaaactgtgactcttcttcctgctgcagatttggatgatttctccaaacaattgcaacaatccatgagcagtgctgactcaactcaggcctaaactcatgcagaccacacaaggcagatgggctatataaacgttttcgcttttccgtttacgatatatagtctactcttgtgcagaatgaattctcgtaactacatagcacaagtagatgtagttaactttaatctcacatagcaatctttaatcagtgtgtaacattagggaggacttgaaagagccaccacattttcaccgaggccacgcggagtacgatcgagtgtacagtgaacaatgctagggagagctgcctatatggaagagccctaatgtgtaaaattaattttagtagtgctatccccatgtgattttaatagcttcttaggagaatgacaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
>>> seq_b = "agagcctaaaaaggacaaaaagaagaaggctgatgaaactcaagccttaccgcagagacagaagaaacagcaaactgtgactcttcttcctgctgcagatttggatgatttctccaaacaattgcaacaatccatgagcagtgctgactcaactcaggcctaaactcatgcagaccacacaaggcagatgggctatataaacgttttcgcttttccgtttacgatatatagtctactcttgtgcagaatgaattctcgtaactacatagcacaagtagatgtagttaactttaatctcacatagcaatctttaatcagtgtgtaacattagggaggacttgaaagagccaccacattttcaccgaggccacgcggagtacgatcgagtgtacagtgaacaatgctagggagagctgcctatatggaagagccctaatgtgtaaaattaattttagtagtgctatccccatgtgattttaatagcttcttaggagaatgac"
```

but the code I'm using is getting stuck on the end sequence_comparison. This code was found online and I'm having real difficulty in trying to find it's problem. The syntax error being provided highlights the s at the beginning of the last piece of code:

```py
def sequence_compare(seq_a, seq_b):
    len1 = len(seq_a)
    len2 = len(seq_b)
    mismatches = []
    for pos in range (0,min(len1,len2)):
        if seq_a[pos] != seq_b[pos]:
            mismatches.append('|')
        else:
            mismatches.append(' ')
    print(seq_a)
    print(mismatches)
    print(seq_b)
sequence_compare(seq_a,seq_b)
```

can anyone help me find the issue with this?

Comment: I figured out my issue in part, I was able to make the code not produce the syntax error but it doesn't provide the comparison. The issue was that the sequence_compare(seq_a, seq_b) wasn't indented or tabbed. But now it won't provide the sequence comparison as it just leaves it blank instead of providing something along the lines of: C - T

Comment: What is the comparison? What do you want to find? Are you trying to find the parts that are not the same of each sequence? So if `seq_a[0:4]` is not the same as `seq_b[0:4]` you want to do what?

Comment: The idea is that it would provide the lines of sequence code up against one another and use the | symbol to mark base pairs that are not similar to one another. The two sequences: seq_a and seq_b are the two that are being compared against one another.

Comment: Ohhhhh looking at the answer below helped. You wanted to see which letter is different to the other sequence. The answer below seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem was that `mismatches` was being displayed as a list, not a string. I've converted it to a string:

**Updated code**

```
def sequence_compare(seq_a, seq_b):
    len1 = len(seq_a)
    len2 = len(seq_b)
    mismatches = ""
    for pos in range (0,min(len1,len2)):
        if seq_a[pos] != seq_b[pos]:
            mismatches += '|'
        else:
            mismatches += ' '
    print(seq_a)
    print(mismatches)
    print(seq_b)

seq_a = "tgaaactcaagccttaccgcagagacagaagaaacagcaaactgtgactcttcttcctgctgcagatttggatgatt"
seq_b = "agagcctaaaaaggacaaaaagaagaaggctgatgaaactcaagccttaccgcagagacagaagaaacagcaaactg"

sequence_compare(seq_a,seq_b)
```

**Output**

```
tgaaactcaagccttaccgcagagacagaagaaacagcaaactgtgactcttcttcctgctgcagatttggatgatt
|  ||  |  ||||||||||   |||  |||| || ||||||| ||||| || |||||||||||| ||| | ||| |
agagcctaaaaaggacaaaaagaagaaggctgatgaaactcaagccttaccgcagagacagaagaaacagcaaactg
```

Comment: I am getting a syntax error on the s in seq_a where you're writing the string. It highlights the extra space and the s and doesn't provide any output

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I think what was wrong was my environment. I used python IDLE, but switched over to a different type of python I guess that I just downloaded off of Microsoft and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In python adding indentation is must, If you don't add indentation at certain place, Your code won't work; Here after declaring the function, You need to add an indentation after declaring the function.

```
def sequence_compare(seq_a, seq_b):
    len1 = len(seq_a)
    len2 = len(seq_b)
    mismatches = []
    for pos in range (0,min(len1,len2)):
        if seq_a[pos] != seq_b[pos]:
            mismatches.append('|')
        else:
            mismatches.append(' ')
    print(seq_a)
    print(mismatches)
    print(seq_b)
```

This code should work as I have added indentation wherever it was needed.